# Je te pardonnerai jamais ça - meaning of "ça"

Tags: sens, pronoms

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

> Je te pardonnerai jamais ça.

The English subtitle translation is "I will never forgive you". What does "ça" mean here? I considered that it could mean "for that", but I think that "I will never forgive you for that" would be expressed as "Je te le pardonnerai jamais".

Comment: Note that in French, just like In english,  *pardonner* can be used either with no direct complement, or with a direct complement. *Je (ne) te pardonnerai jamais* is also correct, there is a just a little nuance (you then don't mention the act for which you will never forgive the person, so this feeling of "unforgiveness" is deeper and more personal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are right considering "for that" as a translation for *ça*.

The meaning is the same between:

> *Je te pardonnerai jamais **ça**.* (pronounced either *J'te pardonnerai...* or *Je t'pardonnerai...*)

and

> *Je te **le** pardonnerai jamais.* (pronounced either *J'te l'pardonnerai...* or *Je t'le pardonnerai...*)

The first sentence is putting more emphasis on the pronoun. An even more emphatic sentence would be:

> ***Ça***, je te **le** pardonnerai jamais.

Formal/literary/school French would use:

> *Je ne te pardonnerai jamais cela.*

I believe Spanish has very similar constructions:

> *Nunca te perdonaré **eso**.*

and

> *Nunca te **lo** perdonaré.*

Comment: I'm not a native Spanish speaker, but AFAIK the more usual construction would be "Nunca te lo perdonaré" and the less usual alternative would be "Nunca te perdonaré *por* eso". Also the most usual sentence in Portuguese ("Nunca te perdoarei por isso") requires the preposition "por".

Comment: I see. There is however no preposition in the well known *perdona nuestras ofensas* | *perdoa-nos as nossas dívidas* (French: *pardonnez-nous nos offenses*).

Comment: @jiliagre True. AFAIK the correct usages in Spanish are "perdonar algo", "perdonar a alguién" and "perdonar a alguién por algo". Same in Portuguese with "perdoar".